# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in applet class using ZK

Tags: java, applet, zk

I got a problem that is taking me days!

I have a applet class that import classes in a external JAR.

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamPanel;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;

public class AppletTela extends JApplet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3517366452510566924L;

    private Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();
    private Webcam webcam = null;
    private WebcamPanel panel = null;
```

I export my applet project for a .Jar file, and try to use it in a web project. 
So in my .Zul file, I put the following coding

```
<applet code="AppletTela" codebase="."  archive="teste.jar" codemsg="ZK is Simple and Rich!" id="ticker"
            width="400px" style="border: 1px" />
```

and my teste.jar is under my WebContent folder.
And Im getting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for the WebcamPanel.

Help me guys.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add jar with Webcam classes to your applet tag. This your looks like this:

```
<applet archive="teste.jar,webcamjar.jar" ... />
```

Comment: thanks for your replay! 
I already do it, but now I'm getting another error, 
I'm getting **Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"**
I'm using slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar, other answers in the forum are suggested to add slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar to the class path. I already do this but still getting the staticloggerbinder. if you have a tip for that, please!  but, regardless I will mark as answered.

Comment: Did you add slf4j-api jar as I mentioned? You should deploy all additional libraries you use. If I'm wrong post some more details...

Comment: Yes I added, I put the slf4j-api.jar under the WebContent folder, and the others libraries that my applet class need to use, and populate the archive attribute with the same library. 

But, there is something that I cannot understand, why is that happen? Should my applet class get the **external classes link** from the class path?

Comment: ClassLoader in java/applet have to have access to code you use. This is possible only when your additional libraries are deployed with applet and they are on server. Browsers download all jars and sometimes cache them, and if there is no jar available, you got error. More, everyone will get error, because these libraries are not custom.

Comment: Ok! I pass it, removing the jars in class path and live only the jar  under the WebContent. But now, Im getting other error, **ExceptionInInitializerError**, no more info! some tip?

Comment: Only this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html check console log (https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) and eventually create new question :)

Comment: Hey tomas! 

I got the error! **java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "webcam.debug" "read")** 

I tried some internet solution, I tried to sign the applet but no progress! 
Did you have any idea?

Comment: If you don't have official certificate, you can only test on local machine, but you should use `exception site list` - https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml. Oracle did a lot of work (read bugs) with security and now it's difficult to get it all working.